# How to pass data between .vue file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using prime vue template and I created login page. I can get user value when i logged in and push this data in object variable. Now I want to use this user data on profile page. How can I do this without import component. Please help

This is my profile page codes

```
<script setup>
import { computed, ref } from 'vue';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import { useLayout } from '@/layout/composables/layout';
import axios from 'axios';
let user = ref({});
const router = useRouter();
const rememberMe = ref(false);
const { layoutConfig } = useLayout();
const e_mail = ref("");
const pass = ref("");
const userData = computed(() => {
    return user;
});
</script>

<template>
    <div class="px-5 min-h-screen flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="border-1 surface-border surface-card border-round py-7 px-4 md:px-7 z-1">
            <label for="">Username</label>
            <span></span>
            <label for="">E-Mail</label>
            <span></span>
            <label for="">Phone</label>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And this is my Login Page codes i tried here emit func but it wasn't worked. So i deleted. Actually i want to pass data without import component but i couldn't. Thank you..

```
<script setup>
import { computed, ref } from 'vue';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import { useLayout } from '@/layout/composables/layout';
import AppConfig from '@/layout/AppConfig.vue';
import axios from 'axios';
let user = ref({});
const router = useRouter();
const rememberMe = ref(false);
const { layoutConfig } = useLayout();
const e_mail = ref("");
const pass = ref("");
const navigateToDashboard = async () => {
    axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/user/login", {email: e_mail.value, password: pass.value})
    .then(response =>  {
        user = response.data.user;
        console.log(user);
        emit('userData', user);
        router.push({ name: 'e-commerce' });
    });
};
const userData = computed(() => {
    return user;
});
</script>

<template>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1600 800" class="fixed left-0 top-0 min-h-screen min-w-screen" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <rect :fill="darkMode ? 'var(--primary-900)' : 'var(--primary-500)'" width="1600" height="800" />
        <path
            :fill="darkMode ? 'var(--primary-800)' : 'var(--primary-400)'"
            d="M478.4 581c3.2 0.8 6.4 1.7 9.5 2.5c196.2 52.5 388.7 133.5 593.5 176.6c174.2 36.6 349.5 29.2 518.6-10.2V0H0v574.9c52.3-17.6 106.5-27.7 161.1-30.9C268.4 537.4 375.7 554.2
        478.4 581z"
        />
        <path
            :fill="darkMode ? 'var(--primary-700)' : 'var(--primary-300)'"
            d="M181.8 259.4c98.2 6 191.9 35.2 281.3 72.1c2.8 1.1 5.5 2.3 8.3 3.4c171 71.6 342.7 158.5 531.3 207.7c198.8 51.8 403.4 40.8 597.3-14.8V0H0v283.2C59 263.6 120.6 255.7 181.8 259.4z"
        />
        <path
            :fill="darkMode ? 'var(--primary-600)' : 'var(--primary-200)'"
            d="M454.9 86.3C600.7 177 751.6 269.3 924.1 325c208.6 67.4 431.3 60.8 637.9-5.3c12.8-4.1 25.4-8.4 38.1-12.9V0H288.1c56 21.3 108.7 50.6 159.7 82C450.2 83.4 452.5 84.9 454.9 86.3z"
        />
        <path :fill="darkMode ? 'var(--primary-500)' : 'var(--primary-100)'" d="M1397.5 154.8c47.2-10.6 93.6-25.3 138.6-43.8c21.7-8.9 43-18.8 63.9-29.5V0H643.4c62.9 41.7 129.7 78.2 202.1 107.4C1020.4 178.1 1214.2 196.1 1397.5 154.8z" />
    </svg>
    <div class="px-5 min-h-screen flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="border-1 surface-border surface-card border-round py-7 px-4 md:px-7 z-1">
            <div class="mb-4">
                <div class="text-900 text-xl font-bold mb-2">Log in</div>
                <span class="text-600 font-medium">Please enter your details</span>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-column">
                <span class="p-input-icon-left w-full mb-4">
                    <i class="pi pi-envelope"></i>
                    <InputText v-model="e_mail" id="email" type="text" class="w-full md:w-25rem" placeholder="Email" />
                </span>
                <span class="p-input-icon-left w-full mb-4">
                    <i class="pi pi-lock"></i>
                    <InputText v-model="pass" id="password" type="password" class="w-full md:w-25rem" placeholder="Password" />
                </span>
                <div class="mb-4 flex flex-wrap gap-3">
                    <div>
                        <Checkbox name="checkbox" v-model="rememberMe" binary class="mr-2"></Checkbox>
                        <label htmlFor="checkbox" class="text-900 font-medium mr-8"> Remember Me </label>
                    </div>
                    <a class="text-600 cursor-pointer hover:text-primary cursor-pointer ml-auto transition-colors transition-duration-300">Reset password</a>
                </div>
                <Button label="Log In" class="w-full" @click="navigateToDashboard"></Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <AppConfig simple />
</template>
```

Comment: so these are two completely separate pages, i.e. you're not creating an SPA for example? have you considered `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`

Comment: @JaromandaX no this is not SPA but i think I have to use localStorage or sessionStorage.

Comment: then ... use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data shared between more than one ccomponent
Such as the auth user data and website settings
Should be in vuex or pinia
Because you need it in the sidebar - navbar - user profile - website settings

If you're going to share all of these components it's going to be bad code

You can save some localStorage data such as the token so that you can use it to fetch the data again when the page is reloaded